# I create simple application and activity doesn't show up every time

Tags: android, android-activity

My application should show an activity for two seconds when I receive an sms but sometimes the activity doesn't show up (the process is still running) and I don't know why (maybe it's some emulator error). Here's my code:

RomariosListener.java:

```
package com.romario.android.smslistener;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class RomariosListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Intent i = new Intent(context, RomariosSmsActivity.class);
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

RomariosSmsActivity.java

```
package com.romario.android.smslistener;
import com.romario.android.smslistener.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RomariosSmsActivity extends Activity {
  private Thread thread;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.romarios_sms_activity);
    thread=  new Thread(){
      @Override
      public void run(){
        try {
          synchronized(this){
            wait(2000);
            finish();
          }
        } catch(Exception e){

        }        
      }
    };
    thread.start();     
  }
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.romario.android.smslistener"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">  
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <receiver  android:name=".RomariosListener">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.romario.android.smslistener.RomariosSmsActivity" android:label="@string/RSA"></activity>              

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
</manifest>
```

Please help me and sorry for my english

Comment: try to add **finally** block after catch statement

Comment: Why do you need synchronized and catch all?

Comment: Sorry guys im really beginner i find code and copy. How should it looks? when i'm delete synchronized(this)- "finish" function stops work

Comment: I add "finally" like this "catch(Exception e){ } finally {} " Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package com.romario.android.smslistener;
import com.romario.android.smslistener.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class RomariosSmsActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.romarios_sms_activity);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! It works but still I have to test this. When I used my previous application after 30 minuts i send sms and activity doesn't show up.

Comment: @user2141238 try then add <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> to both, activity tag in AndroidManifest and to the intent you instantiate to start the activity.